# Is there an easy way to use intellij for liferay theme development?

Tags: intellij-idea, themes, liferay

I recently switched from eclipse and netbeans to intellij, but I have also liferay stuff to do and intelliJ seems to lack a decent liferay integration.

Does someone know how to use intelliJ for that, with as much of intelliJs comfort as possible :-/

As the themes are no simple java project the import stuff doesn't seem to recognize it properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into the maven integration for Liferay (depending on the version of Liferay you're using - the more recent the version, the better the maven integration) and just import a pure maven project. The layout of this differs a bit from the usual ant-based SDK.

But of course you can also use the pure Ant buildfiles you find in the plugins sdk. As there's typically no java in a theme, it doesn't make a lot of differences.

Not wanting to start IDE wars here, but you also might consider Liferay IDE (or Developer Studio, it's EE-Version) for theme-related development. As there's no Java development done in themes, the conflict of changing tools should be handleable. I wouldn't want to work in both IDEs for Java development again (been there, done that), but for themes I can imagine just going the easy route - it's mainly CSS that you edit.

Comment: Well, that's of course the easy way. I'm just  surprised that there is no decent integration in IntelliJ as liferay is at least in Europe pretty commonly used...
Currently I have managed to import the build.xml and fiddle around with the path o get it to work, but it feels more like a hack than a solution ;-)

Comment: It should be extremely easy. Put a build.${username}.properties file into the plugin-sdk's root folder, overriding the values you need to override from build.properties (that's located there). Then you just need to run ant - no more customization needed. At least typically.

Comment: Also - there's only so many resources to take care of a decent IDE integration. Liferay has decided to go for eclipse (esp. given the available resources) but, of course, everybody is free to create more integrations.